# decrypt/encrypt xor algorithm in C

Tags: c, xor

Here, I'm trying to encrypt a message using XOR. However, when I run the program, I'm getting weird output (random outputs). I guess I'm missing something here.

[image]

my sample of code:

```
/*
* Description: Decipher the message using XOR and print it.
* Parameters:
*   cipher: The cipher of the message (With the key embedded at the start)
*   keyLength: The length of the key at the start of the message
*Return:
*   None.
*Note:
    Do not use any additional variables for this challenge.
*/

void print_cipher_message(unsigned char cipher[], int keyLength) {
    // TODO: complete the function
    //keyLength = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(cipher) && i <= keyLength; i++) {
        
            i % keyLength;
    
        cipher[i] = cipher[i] ^ keyLength;
      // i% keyLength;// i % ;//cipher[i] % sizeof(keyLength);
        
        printf("%c", cipher);
    }

}


int main() {
    
    unsigned char cipher[] = "\x12\x56\xd4\x61\x26\xbb\x7b\x3a\xbd\x7c\x31\xf4\x61\x3e\xbb\x65\x25\xf4\x7b\x25\xf4\x73\x76\x97\x40\x1f\x99\x57";
    int keyLength = 3;


    //print the cipher message
    print_cipher_message(cipher, keyLength);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The expecting result is as the following:

```
/*
    EXAMPLE:
    cipher="\x31\xf4\x61\x7a\x33\xb8\x7e\x39\xf4\x65\x39\xa6\x7e\x32\xf5\x33"
    keyLength=3;

    then the cipher is:
    "\x31\xf4\x61\x7a\x33\xb8\x7e\x39\xf4\x65\x39\xa6\x7e\x32\xf5\x33"
    ^----Key-----^^-------------------Message------------------------^

    */
```

I Would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: What do you expect from the line `i % keyLength;`? Also, you xor with `keyLength`, which is 3, so actually just flipping the lowest two bits

Comment: You can't use `strlen` with something that is in theory might contain zero bytes in the middle.

Comment: I hope this is a toy project, as XOR is inherently insecure unless key-length >= message-length (and even then, there are issues with this approach).

Comment: @EugeneSh. There is no length argument being passed, so it must be a NUL-terminated string.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn Then the whole exercise is broken. Plain text characters may very well overlap with key characters here and there resulting in zeros in the ciphertext.

Comment: Think about the algorithm. Write down what you would do manually for the example in your code. I guess it's something like this: The key is in `cipher[0]` to `cipher[2]`. The message is in `cipher[3]` to the end. You want to calculate `c[0] ^ c[3]`, `c[1] ^ c[4]`, `c[2] ^ c[5]`, `c[0] ^ c[6]` etc. Since the array is not terminated with `'\0'` and can probably contain `'\0'` values anywhere, you cannot use `strlen` but would have to pass `sizeof(cipher)` from `main` to `print_cipher_message`

Comment: @Bodo `sizeof cipher` will only give the right value if done in `main`, so be careful with this suggestion

Comment: @EugeneSh. That's a good point. I suppose the key could be contrived so that can't happen (e.g., by using only char values that can't appear in the message). Clearly this exercise is more about writing for loops than about security.

Comment: What is that "No additional variables" requirement? How can you count without an additional variable?

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of challenge and this was the point I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you need to understand question correctly. Your question states that key is embedded at start of your cipher and its length is `keyLength`. So you need to separate this part and xor it with the rest of cipher.

Code should be similar to this:

```
void print_cipher_message(unsigned char cipher[], int keyLength) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen((char*)cipher) - keyLength; i++) {
        cipher[i + keyLength] = cipher[i + keyLength] ^ cipher[i % keyLength];
    }

    printf("%s", cipher + keyLength);
}
```

I wrote it off top of head quickly without debugging, so it may have bugs. In addition, question is not correct itself. it needs length of cipher and we cannot really use `strlen()` for it.

Comment: As the array is not a NUL terminated string and might contain NUL bytes anywhere in the ciphertext, `strlen` should not be used. Instead, the size of the array should be passed from `main` to the function.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't really understand the algorithm and I'm quite new to the language. If I understand correctly, the key here is embedded to the first of the cipher text and the cipher itself is decrypted with that key?

Comment: @Bodo it seems the function body is predefined, that's why I told question is not correct.

Comment: @hadeelKh yes, but what you said was stated in question. read it carefully. :)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of problems I see right away:

1. You're asking `printf` to print a `char` (`%c`) but are passing a pointer to `char` instead of a `char`.
2. There's a line `i % keyLength` that doesn't do anything, it just performs a calculation and discards the results.

Also you're calling `strlen` every time through the loop, which is going to be kind of expensive.

I think what you're expected to do here is have two indexes, one that loops over the range 0 to `keyLength`, and another that iterates over the string to encode (starting at index `keyLength`). The function ends when the second index reaches the end of the string.